# Redraw view during MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in onTouchEvent()

Tags: android, touch

I have created my own component which extends `RelativeLayout`, inside it I have a field of `View` type which is being positioned with margins:

[image]

Blue quad represents my parent view, and a red circle is a child.

Now I want to allow user to move this red circle while moving a finger on a screen. 
This is my `onTouchEvent()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            // finger touches the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                marginX = (int)event.getX();
                marginY = (int)event.getY();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)pointer.getLayoutParams(); // pointer is this red circle
                lp.setMargins(marginX, marginY, 0, 0);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
            // finger leaves the screen
            break;
    }


    return true;
}
```

But I quickly found out that it doesn't refresh it's position while user is moving his finger on a screen, but instead it does it only when user releases his finger from the screen. So basically, when I move my finger, circle stays in a same position, but when I stop moving, circle is drawn in new position. I tried using `invalidate()` method on both, parent and child views, but it didn't help. I assume that it may have something to do with UI thread, but I don't have access to `runOnUiThread()' method as it's not an`Activity`.

EDIT:
I passed an activity to my class, so that I can use `runOnUiThread()`. My `case: ACTION_MOVE` now looks like this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:      
    marginX = (int)event.getX();
    marginY = (int)event.getY();

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)pointer.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(marginX, marginY, 0, 0);
        pointer.invalidate();
        }
    });

break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simple pointer you can draw it on `Canvas` as `Drawable`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    pointer.setBounds(marginX, marginY, marginX + pointerWidth, marginY + pointerHeight);
    pointer.draw(canvas);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

And then call `invalidate()` on pointer in `onTouchEvent()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need drag and drop function

Refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Thank you link, but as I see it's only available for Android 4.0+. Isn't it possible to achieve this on previous versions? I need to support 2.3 version.